# Loop through dates in hash table?

Tags: powershell

I have a hash table in Powershell that looks like this (`$hash_dates.GetEnumerator() | sort -Property name`):

```
11/1/2016 12:00:00 AM          5
11/2/2016 12:00:00 AM          3
11/4/2016 12:00:00 AM          2
```

The key is of type DateTime.

I am running a for loop to catch all the dates (dates only, times don't matter thus all midnight) and pull out each value in the hash table based on the date. The code:

```
$startdate = (get-date).AddDays(-30)
$today = get-date -format G
for($i = $startdate; $i -lt $today; $i=$i.AddDays(1))
{
   $z = $i -split " "
   $z = [datetime]$z[0]
   $z = Get-Date $z -format G
   "Comparing $z to: "
   $hash_dates.Keys | ? { $hash_dates[$_] -eq $z }
}
```

I used the `-format G` and `split` to ensure the format matches. But the loop never finds any results (even though it loops through 11/1/2016 etc). Am I missing something?

Comment: `$today` is a string. `$i -lt $today` makes no sense

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Hmm. But the loop works just fine. It starts at today-30 and loops until today, and outputs `Comparing <DATE> to:` each pass. It just doesn't find any hash keys.

Comment: @Zeno: The only reason `$i -lt $today` works as intended is that _string_ `$today` is re-converted to `[datetime]` _for the comparison_, because the _LHS_ is of type `[datetime]`, but there's no good reason to represent `$today` as a string to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your **hashtable keys are `[datetime]` objects**, there is **no need to use date *strings*** and string parsing at all:

```
$today = (Get-Date).Date # Note the .Date part, which omits the time portion
$startdate = $today.AddDays(-30)

# Note the change from -lt to -le to include today
for($i = $startdate; $i -le $today; $i = $i.AddDays(1))
{
  # Note that `echo` is an alias for `Write-Output`, which is the default,
  # so no need for an explicit output command.
  "Looking for $i..." 
  # Simply try to access the hashtable with $i as the key, which
  # either outputs nothing ($null), or outputs the value for that key.
  $hash_dates.$i
}
```

Re `echo` / `Write-Output` / default output: note that your status messages will become of your *data* (output) stream, which may be undesired.
Consider using [`Write-Information`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn998020.aspx) instead.

---

Here's a **simplified solution** that demonstrates the expressiveness of PowerShell:

```
$today = (get-date).Date

# Construct an array with all dates of interest.
$dates = -30..0 | % { $today.AddDays($_) } # % is a built-in alias for ForEach-Object

# Pass the entire array as the hashtable "subscript", which returns
# the values for all matching keys while ignoring keys that don't exist.
$hash_dates[$dates]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
$startdate = (get-date).AddDays(-30)
$today = get-date -format G
for($i = $startdate; $i -lt $today; $i=$i.AddDays(1))
{
   $z = $i -split " "
   $z = [datetime]$z[0]
   Echo "Comparing $z to: "
   $z = Get-Date $z
   $hash_dates.$z

}
```

Comment: While accessing the hashtable by key (`$hash_dates.$z`) in order to retrieve the value is a step in the right direction,
your answer doesn't address all the unnecessary and fragile date-to-string conversions and parsing.